# json_encode preserve line breaks in given text

Tags: php, json, pdo, newline

Given a dataset returned from an sql query, some fields of which are of type "text" and may contain arbitrary whitespaces, I need to `json_encode` it.

```
$dataset=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($dataset);
```

Which may end up with something like

```
[
{
 "field1":"this one is ok, \"double quotes\" are escaped automatically",
 "field2":"But line breaks are not
and so they ruin json"
}
]
```

I cannot change text on the sql side (neither in tables, nor in queries), i need to replace line breaks to \n sequence on the php side.
Does that mean i can not use the stock `json_encode`? It escapes double quotes but not line breaks - wtf?
I cannot just replace line breaks to spaces - i need them preserved (as `\n`).
I cannot replace all line breaks to `\n`, because that will affect line breaks after json's brackets, outside the strings.

Comment: Not happening, https://3v4l.org/t7Ub2

Comment: You should do a `var_dump()` instead of an echo to see what you really have. And always check the real output, not what you see in the browser.

Comment: Gotcha! It must be the problem of the IIS's php only (pls don't ask me why i used php on IIS). On Apache it works fine. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.  Your question has been rolled back to its previous state. For more information, please visit the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP_EOL` and `str_replace`:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'field1' => 'this one is ok, "double quotes" are escaped automatically',
    'field2' => 'But line breaks are not
and so they ruin json'
];

$new_json = str_replace(PHP_EOL,"\n",json_encode($array));
echo $new_json;
//output: {"field1":"this one is ok, \"double quotes\" are escaped automatically","field2":"But line breaks are not\nand so they ruin json"}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/H2gBT)